# Component like Timeli app in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am posting the question again with more clarity.
I am trying to develop a component similar to the UI for timeline component in "Timeli" app.Ia m not sure how to start or which iOS controls to use for this .The requirement is to show the years in a horizontal table view.Pinching on the tableview should expand that particular cell and at some particular point the cell should  break into the different months in that year.If the user further try to expand a particular cell by pinching then that cell should break into the different days .Reverse should also work.It would be great if anyone can help me with some tips or suggestions to star developing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that particular app, but I can give some general advice: browse through the open source components at [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com); find one that is similar to what you want to create; download the source code and study it.

Even if you can't find exactly what you want, you might learn some techniques that will help you figure out how to build the control you want to build.

If you want more specific help, you're going to have to make an attempt, and then ask a specific question where you explain what you're doing and what's not working. Generic "how do I build this?" questions don't usually work too well here, because nobody knows where you are starting from.